# my code doesn't draw a line, it only draws a very tiny circle

Tags: swift, drawing

My code isn't behaving the way I want it, why is the so? I don't understand what went wrong. So I'm playing around with swift, trying to transition from android to swift, I'm trying to make this simple app that draws lines, its not working as I want it, can someone please help me with what I'm doing wrong?

```
 //
//  DrawView.swift
//  IOSTouch

import Foundation
import UIKit

class DrawView: UIView {
    var currentLine: Line?
    var finishedLines = [Line]();
    //for debug
    let line1 = Line(begin: CGPoint(x:50,y:50), end: CGPoint(x:100,y:100));
    let line2 = Line(begin: CGPoint(x:50,y:100), end: CGPoint(x:100,y:300));



    func strokeLine(line: Line){
        //Use BezierPath to draw lines
        let path = UIBezierPath();
        path.lineWidth = 5;
        path.lineCapStyle = CGLineCap.round;

        path.move(to: line.begin);
        path.addLine(to: line.end);
        path.stroke(); //actually draw the path
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

        //draw the finished lines
        UIColor.black.setStroke() //finished lines in black
        for line in finishedLines{
            strokeLine(line: line);
        }

        //for debug
        strokeLine(line: line1);
        strokeLine(line: line2);

        //draw current line if it exists
        if let line = currentLine {
            UIColor.red.setStroke(); //current line in red
            strokeLine(line: line);
        }
    }
    //Override Touch Functions
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        print(#function) //for debugging
        let touch = touches.first!; //get first touch event and unwrap optional
        let location = touch.location(in: self); //get location in view co-ordinate
        currentLine = Line(begin: location, end: location);
        setNeedsDisplay(); //this view needs to be updated
    }

    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        //TODO

        setNeedsDisplay()
    }

    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        //TODO

        setNeedsDisplay()
    }

    override func touchesCancelled(_ touches: Set<UITouch>?, with event: UIEvent?) {
        //TODO

    }
    @IBInspectable var finishedLineColor: UIColor = UIColor.black {
        didSet {
            setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }
    @IBInspectable var currentLineColor: UIColor = UIColor.red {
        didSet {
            setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }
    @IBInspectable var lineThickness: CGFloat = 10 {
        didSet {
            setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }
}
```

**another file**

```
import Foundation
import CoreGraphics

struct Line {
    var begin = CGPoint.zero
    var end = CGPoint.zero
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is works, I use it:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var firstPoint: CGPoint?
    var secondPoint: CGPoint?
    var currentLine: CAShapeLayer?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    func addLine(fromPoint start: CGPoint, toPoint end:CGPoint) {
        let line = CAShapeLayer()
        let linePath = UIBezierPath()
        linePath.move(to: start)
        linePath.addLine(to: end)
        line.path = linePath.cgPath
        line.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        line.lineWidth = 3
        line.lineJoin = kCALineJoinRound
        self.view.layer.addSublayer(line)
    }

    func setCurrentLine(fromPoint start: CGPoint, toPoint end: CGPoint) {
        let line = CAShapeLayer()
        let linePath = UIBezierPath()
        linePath.move(to: start)
        linePath.addLine(to: end)
        line.path = linePath.cgPath
        line.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        line.lineWidth = 3
        line.lineJoin = kCALineJoinRound
        currentLine = line
        if let current = currentLine {
            self.view.layer.addSublayer(current)
        }
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        firstPoint = touches.first?.location(in: self.view)
    }

    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        currentLine?.removeFromSuperlayer()
        currentLine = nil
        if let first = firstPoint, let current = touches.first?.location(in: self.view) {
            setCurrentLine(fromPoint: first, toPoint: current)
        }
    }



    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        secondPoint = touches.first?.location(in: self.view)
        if let first = firstPoint, let second = secondPoint {
            addLine(fromPoint: first, toPoint: second)
            currentLine?.removeFromSuperlayer()
            currentLine = nil
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should work now

override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set, with event: UIEvent?) {

```
    print(#function) 
    let touch = touches.first!
    let location = touch.location(in: self);
    currentLine?.end = location;
    setNeedsDisplay();
```

}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set, with event: UIEvent?) {

```
    print(#function) //for debugging
    if var line = currentLine {
        let touch = touches.first!;
        let location = touch.location(in: self);
        line.end = location;
        finishedLines.append(line);
    }
    currentLine = nil;
    setNeedsDisplay();
}

override func touchesCancelled(_ touches: Set<UITouch>?, with event: UIEvent?) {
    print(#function) //for debugging
    currentLine = nil;
    setNeedsDisplay();
}
```